# how to extract firebase database as an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to coding and a basic answer would be very much appreciated.

when extracting the firebase data using the val() function in Javascript, I am able to get the data as an object such as :

```
obj1 : {
        obj1.1 :{
                 data1 : "xyz",
                 data2 : "abc"
                }
        obj1.2 :{
                 data1 : "qwe",
                 data2 : "rty"
                }
        }
```

obj2 : {
        ....
       }
however,
I want the data in the array format such as:

```
obj1 : [
        obj1.1 :{
                 data1 : "xyz",
                 data2 : "abc"
                }
        obj1.2 :{
                 data1 : "qwe",
                 data2 : "rty"
                }
        ]
    obj2 : [
            ....
           ]
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> you can use this converter to convert the `firebase` object to array

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);


app.controller("ctrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    var convertor = function(object) {
        var newArray = [];

        for (var key in object) {
            var objectA = { name: key , list: []};
            if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                for (var keyA in object[key]) {
                    objectA.list.push(object[key][keyA]);
                }
            }
            newArray.push(objectA);
        }
        return newArray;
    }

    var array = {
        obj1: {
            "obj1.1": { data1: "a", data2: "b" },
            "obj1.2": { data1: "c", data2: "d" }
        },
        obj2: {
            "obj1.1": { data1: "e", data2: "f" },
            "obj1.2": { data1: "g", data2: "h" }
        }
    }

    $scope.data = convertor(array);
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in data">
        {{item.name}}
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="child in item.list">
                <label>data1: {{child.data1}}</label> |
                <label>data2: {{child.data2}}</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```